# Resistor help with DC voltage

Tags: resistors

I purchased LEDs with 100 ohm resistors for 12VDC  and 450 resistors for 5VDC.  I am replacing bulbs in my vehicle instrument cluster. When I test them at 12VDC they light up just fine, but my vehicle is pushing 13.4VDC and none of the bulbs light up. How do I adjust for the extra voltage?

Comment: If they work at 12V I don't see a plausible reason why they shouldn't at 13.4V, how did you test them at 12V?

Comment: I am using a 12v dc 2amp ac adapter to test the board

Comment: I am using super bright 5mm LED 3000 MCD  WITH voltage dropping resistors

Comment: Are you certain you have the polarity right?

Comment: Choose resistor nominals according to spec. For instance max current 20 mA, voltage drop 3.2V. 13.4-3.2/0.02=560. 680 Ohm closest value. You can connect 3 LEDs in serial to reduce amount of resistors and increase efficiency.

Comment: I expect the 450 Ohm resistors are for use with 12 volts, and the 100 Ohm for 5 volts.  You need the higher resistance for the higher voltage to keep similar current through the LEDs at the two supply voltages.